# How is marker recognition done in ar.js? How can we improve recognition efficiency?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, artoolkit, ar.js

I want to know how exactly the marker is generated/recognized so that I can make it more efficient in my code. Is there any way of making something a marker other than a patt file?

I was trying to use alphabets as markers and when displaying many letter-markers in one frame, it fails to detect the right one. So I wanted to make any random, clear image with the black border to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jerome's maker generator](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html) to produce a marker of any image, but the image should be rotationally assymetric as per the [ARToolKit docs](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit-docs/blob/master/3_Marker_Training/marker_training.md)

Comment: Well I guess Jerome's maker generator was not generating the right kind of patt files needed for good recognition. My patt file was really unclear. It would recognize similar kind of markers. That is why I wanted to know if we could change the js in such a way that custom image recognition can be used instead of patt file markers